# Retornar mais de uma lista de dados Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Fiz uma página inicial usando django, estou carregando meus slides e menus dinamicamente e ficou perfeito. Coloquei tanto o menu quanto o footer através de include e funcionou 100%.

Agora me deparei com um problema, o menu de produtos carregados na página principal quando eu clico nele é direcionado para uma página especifica daquele produto, ele pega perfeitamente os dados do produto e tudo mais, o único problema é que o carregamento  dos produtos  dentro do meu menu, mesmo estando no include ele perde os dados, como eu resolvo isso ?

view.py​

```
def list_product(request, template_name='home/index.html'):
    # product = Product.objects.all()
    product = Product.objects.filter(status='True')
    products = {'list_products': product}
    return render(request, template_name, products)

def about_product(request, pk, template_name='home/product.html'):
    about_product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    return render(request, template_name, {'about_product': about_product})
```

Comment: Olá, @MarceloLop3s. É possível você também mostrar o código do seu template?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que uma boa opção seria você separar os contextos.

```
def list_product(request, template_name='home/index.html'):
    menu_all_products = Product.objects.all()
    page_active_products = Product.objects.filter(status='True')
    context = {
        'menu_all_products': menu_all_products,
        'page_active_products', page_active_products,
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Daí no seu template você vai acessar no menu os produtos que devem aparecer lá, e na página de listagem os seus produtos que usou no `.filter(status='True')`